Why does this method give the wrong probability?

Consider three sets $E_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $F_1 = \{1, 3, 4\}$, and $G_1 = \{2, 3, 4, 5\}.$ Two elements are chosen at random, without replacement, from the set $E_1;$ let $S_1$ denote the set of these chosen elements. Let $E_2 = E_1 - S_1$ and $F_2 = F_1 \cup S_1.$ Two elements are then chosen at random, without replacement, from the set $F_2;$ let $S_2$ denote the set of these chosen elements. Let $G_2 = G_1 \cup S_2.$ Finally, two elements are chosen at random, without replacement, from the set $G_2;$ let $S_3$ denote the set of these chosen elements. Let $E_3 = E_2 \cup S_3.$
Given that $E_1 = E_3,$ what is the conditional probability of the event $S_1 = \{1, 2\}\,?$

Using the definition of conditional probability $$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)},$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
S_1 & F_2 = F_1 \cup S_1 & S_2 \\
\hline
\{1, 2\} & \{1, 2, 3, 4\} & \{1, 2\} \text{ (3 cases)} \\
\hline
\{1, 3\} & \{1, 3, 4\} & \{1, x\} \text{ (2 cases)} \\
\hline
\{2, 3\} & \{1, 2, 3, 4\} & \{x, y\} \text{ ($\binom{4}{2}$ cases)} \\
\hline
\end{array}
So, my answer is $\frac{3}{3+2+6}.$ But it does not match the correct answer. Where is my mistake?

Please, use descriptive titles. "Mistake in my method" says nothing about the subject of the question.

The problem with your approach is that a simple counting approach does not work; the sizes of $F_2$ and $G_2$ affect the probabilities of making satisfactory draws and you need to take this into account.  So with a larger table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
S_1 & F_2 = F_1 \cup S_1 & S_2 & G_2=G_1 \cup S_2 & S_3 & \mathbb P(S_1, S_2,S_3)\\
\hline
\{1, 2\} & \{1, 2, 3, 4\} & \{1, 2\},\{1, 3\},\{1, 4\} & \{1,2,3,4,5\} & \{1,2\} & \frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{10} \\
\hline
\{1, 3\} & \{1, 3, 4\} & \{1, 3\},\{1, 4\} & \{1,2,3,4,5\} & \{1,3\} & \frac13\times \frac23\times \frac1{10} \\
\hline
\{2, 3\} & \{1, 2, 3, 4\} & \{1, 2\},\{1, 3\},\{1, 4\} & \{1,2,3,4,5\} & \{2,3\} & \frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{10} \\
\hline
\{2, 3\} & \{1, 2, 3, 4\} & \{2, 3\},\{2, 4\},\{3, 4\} & \{2,3,4,5\} & \{2,3\} & \frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{6} \\
\hline
\end{array}
and your conditional probability becomes
$$\dfrac{\frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{10}}{\frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{10}+\frac13\times \frac23\times \frac1{10} + \frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{10} +\frac13\times \frac36\times \frac1{6} }=\dfrac15.$$
